# $I＝(2,x＋1)$ is not principal in $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2＋5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I＝(a＋bx)$ be an nonzero ideal of quotient ring $R＝\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2＋5)$, here $(a＋bx)$'s $x$ means image of $x$ in quotient ring $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2＋7)$.
Then, why $I＝(2,x＋1)$ is not principal?

My proof: Suppose $I$ is principle, then $I＝(f)$ for some $f∈R$.
Then, $2∈I$, so, $2$ need to be written like a form $fg$, $f,g∈R$.
But I cannot proceed from here.. This is a quotient ring, so I cannot say $f,g$ are constants.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a general result classifying maximal ideals in $A:=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. An ideal $I\subseteq A$ is maximal iff there is a (non-zero) prime $p\in \mathbb{Z}$  and an irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in B:=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $I=(p,F(x))$ where $f(x)$ is the reduction of $F(x)$ in $B$. Hence no maximal ideal in $A$ is principal. Your ideal $I$ has the property that $A/I \cong \mathbb{F}_2$ is a field, hence $I$ is maximal.

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157461/why-is-2-1-sqrt-5-not-principal). It is the same if we identity $x$ with $\sqrt{-5}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $I=(2,x+1)$, we have $I^2=(4,2x+2,x^2+2x+1)$. This can be simplified as follows: $$\begin{align}I^2&=(4,2x+2,x^2+2x+1)\\&=(4,2x+2,x^2+2x+5)\\&=(4,2x+2,2x)\\&=(4,2,2x)\\&=(2,2x)\\&=(2)\end{align}$$

Thus $I^2=(2)$. Suppose that $I=(\alpha)$ is principal, then $(\alpha^2)=(2)$. This means that $2\mid \alpha^2$, and $\alpha^2\mid 2$, so $\alpha^2=2u$ for some unit $u$. Taking the norm, we get $N(\alpha)^2=4$, so $N(\alpha)=2$. But this is impossible, as $$N(\alpha)=a^2+5b^2\neq 2$$

Comment: This is somehow a little to short... Why do we have $I^2=2I$ (using or not using the assumption $I=(\alpha)$) ?

Comment: @dan_fulea I've updated my answer. Also, my answer contained a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I will write formally $w=\sqrt{-5}$ instead of $x$ modulo the ideal generated in $\Bbb Z[x]$ by $(x^2+5)$. So $w^2=-5$. Let $R$ be the quotient ring $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2+5)$. (We may formally write now $R=\Bbb Z[w]=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$...)

Observe that there is a ring isomorphism $R\to R$, $a+bw\to \overline{a+bw}:=a-bw$, induced by $x\to -x$. (Since the generator $(x^2+5)$ of the quotient ideal is mapped into an element, in fact the same element, of the quotient idea.) Here and below, $a,b\in \Bbb Z$. Then there is a multiplicative "norm" map $R\to \Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$ defined by
$$
N(a+bw) = (a+bw)(a-bw)=a^2+5b^2\ .
$$
Assume now that the given ideal is principal, and let us write $2=fg$, $1+w=fh$. We pass to the norms and get:
$$
\begin{aligned}
4 &= 2^2+5\cdot 0^2 = N(2)=N(fg)=N(f)\; N(g)\ ,\\
6 &= 1^2+5\cdot 1^2 = N(1+w)=N(fh)=N(f)\; N(h)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so $N(f)$ divides in $\Bbb Z$ both $4$ and $6$, so it non-zero, positive, and further either $1$ or $2$. If $N(f)=1$, then $f\bar f=1$, so $f$ is a unit, contradiction, since $1$ is not in the given ideal $(2,x+1)$, as seen by computing $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2+5)/(2)$. So $N(f)=2$. But there is no solution to $a^2+5b^2=2$, since this immediately implies $b=0$ (else $5b^2>2$ already), and $a^2=2$ has no solution in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Nekojiru I'll take a look now at that question...

Answer (score 2):

The other two answers are fine, but I wanted to provide a proof which uses no machinery at all.

Because $x^2 + 5 = 0$ in $R$, all elements of $R$ have the form $ax+b$.

So, suppose for a contradiction that $f$ exists and write $f = ax+b$.  Note that $2\in (f)$ and $(f)\neq R$ by hypothesis, so the next proposition gives us the only possibility for $f$.

**Proposition**:  If $2\in (f)$ and $(f)\neq R$, then $f = \pm 2$.

Since $2\in(f)$, we must be able to find $g = cx + d$ with $fg = 2$.
This gives $$2 = (ax+b)(cx+d) = acx^2 + (ad+bc)x +bd = bd-5ac + (ad+bc) x.$$ which leads to the system of equations $$\begin{cases} bd-5ac &= 2\\ ad+bc &= 0\end{cases}.$$

If $b = 0$, the first equation gives $-5ac = 2$, giving an obvious contradiction.   Thus, we must have $b\neq 0$.  Since $(f) = (-f)$, we may therefore assume that $b > 0$.  The second equation can now be solved for $c$, giving $c = - \frac{ad}{b}$.  Substituting this into the first equation, we find $bd + 5a\frac{ad}{b} = 2$, which simplifies to $(b^2 + 5a^2) d  = 2b$.

This tells you that $b^2 + 5a^2$ divides $2b$.  However, $b^2 > 2b$ unless $b\leq 2$.  Thus, we have two cases to consider:  $b=1$ or $b=2$.

If $b=1$, we find $(1+5a^2)d = 2$ which obviously implies that $a = 0$.  But then $f = 1$, so is a unit, so $(f) = R$, giving a contradiction.

If $b=2$, we find $(4+5a^2)d = 4$, which again implies $a=0$.  Thus, $f=2$.  $\square$

So, we now know that $f = \pm 2$.  Can $x+1\in (f)$?  Well if so, this means that there is an $h = Cx + D$ with $fh = \pm2(Cx+D) = x+1$.  This gives $2C = \pm 1$ and $2D = \pm 1$, which obviously has no solution.  Thus, the case $f=\pm 2$ is ruled out.  Having ruled out all possible choices for $f$, the ideal $(2,x+1)\subseteq R$ must be not principal.

Comment: This answer has the advantage over the others in that it's about as elementary as possible.  On the other hand, the other answers have important ideas which will be crucial to solving more difficult problems later on.  I'd encourage the OP to study all the answers carefully.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "Then, why $I＝(2,x＋1)$ is not principal?"

**Answer:** There is a general result (1) classifying maximal ideals in $A:=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. An ideal $I\subseteq A$ is maximal iff there is a (non-zero) prime $p\in \mathbb{Z}$  and an irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in B:=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $I=(p,F(x))$ where $f(x)$ is the reduction of $F(x)$ in $B$. Hence no maximal ideal in $A$ is principal. Your ideal $I$ has the property that $A/I \cong \mathbb{F}_2$ is a field, hence $I$ is maximal. The proof of (1) may be found in a(ny) book on field theory I believe. You may also find online notes with an elementary proof.